# Dynamically generating files and providing those files for download in Google App engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, download

I am creating a web app in google app engine using java which dynamically generate an HTML file. The requirement is such that if the Html file size increases from a certain limit (say 3 mb), then it should be split into two files and zipped together and that zip file should be sent back as the response.

I would like help on how and where to create those temporary HTML files and then zip it, in google app engine as i guess GAE doesnt allow to write on the filesystem.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the blobstore like a filesystem.  Experimentally, they've even added access via the File api!

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Google Cloud Storage. The advantage of this one is that once the file is produced, you can easily write scripts to manipulate the files through gsutil.

Comment: thanks huges....you solution seems very nice....but I am totally new to GAE and would request you to help a little more by providing some code snippet or related links for that....thanks

Comment: Hi, Here you go : Google Cloud Storage (https://developers.google.com/storage/) ; examples of code to use Google Cloud Storage with Google App Engine : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/

Comment: In order to offer the files for download, you have to choices : 1/ write a servlet to serve the files (very easy) 2/ If your files are images it is even easier with the imagesService (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview)

Comment: If you need to copy the files from Google App Engine, you can connect using the gsutil program. Extremelly easy to use : https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil